# How to get onclick for an HTML object?

Tags: javascript

Using vanilla JS I would like to know if would be possible to see the property onclick on a HTML object (div)

```
for (var name in element) {
        if(name == "onclick"){
            // do smt
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just use `element.onclick` to retrieve it

Comment: I would like to know how to get the propert onclick for an element, as state on Mozilla onclick looks like a property of an object https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.onclick

Comment: Yeah, it's a property. It will only have a value if it's set. `click` handlers are more often bound with `element.addEventListener` (and `element.attachEvent`), and there's no way to retrieve. May I ask what the point of this is?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, if you posted like a question I would be glad to accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of enumerating properties of `element`, you can immediately retrieve the `onclick` **property** of `element` with:

```
var clickHandler = element.onclick;
```

Events nowadays are bound with `addEventListener` (and `attachEvent` in old IE), which allow for multiple handlers per event type. Setting the `onevent` property only allows for one handler, can be overwritten, and normally isn't the way to bind handlers in a web page.

Unfortunately, you are not able to retrieve any listeners bound with `addEventListener` (and `attachEvent`), without writing a wrapper function that tracks them...for example:

```
var events = [];
function addEvent(element, eventName, callback) {
    element.addEventListener(eventName, callback, false);
    var found = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
        if (events[i].el === element) {
            found = true;
            events[i].list.push(callback);
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!found) {
        events.push({
            el: element,
            list: [callback]
        });
    }
}

function viewEvents(element) {
    for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
        if (events[i].el === element) {
            return events[i].list;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

And you'd use it like:

```
var div = document.getElementById("some_id");
addEvent(div, "click", function () {
    console.log("whatever");
});

console.log(viewEvents(div));
```

(of course, you'd need a wrapper for `removeEventListener` that removes handlers from `events` too)